# How does the Trophy System work?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I like playing as sniper, and this one seems more tempting to use than flashbang or smoke grenade.
However, I can't figure out its use.
The description says it can deflect up to two projectiles.

I am equipped with Blind Eye and Assassin Pro, and I have the ghillie suit unlocked, so basically, I am invisible to anyone and anything at all times, as long as I don't move.

What would be the tactical uses of the Trophy System, and how does it work?

Also, once deployed, can I relocate it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it simply destoys enemy rockets and granades like

- predator missiles
- rpg rockets
- flashbangs
- bouncing bettys
- i.m.s
- the "big" shots of an ac-130
- ...

so you can mount it where the action is, let it do its work, protect your teammates and earn points, while you can hide whereever you want to.

to read more, take a look at [callofduty.wikia.com](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_System).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I read `... it can deflect up to two projectiles` but projectile can also means bullet in french. I didn't understand it didn't do any difference when an enemy was firing in my direction.

Answer (score 1):

@oezi covered how it works pretty nicely, tactically speaking as a sniper it is mainly good for helping defend a position that is good to snipe from but vulnerable to projectile explosives.

As for whether it is the right tactical equipment to use for you as a sniper depends on how you play.  You have perks that make you quite invisible to the enemy but you like to stay in one spot and depending on what playlists you play as soon as you've sniped someone they know where you are and can attempt to flank you.  Therefore having the trophy system might help protect you from speculative grenades flung in your direction.

Personally my sniper class has Slight of Hand, Hardline and Dead Silence so I'm visible to predator missiles and the like so having the trophy system on an open map (e.g. Mission) is really useful, however on a map like Resistance/Underground where you have more chance of being indoors maybe less so unless the enemy are really tooled up with grenades.

I actually prefer having portable radar as my tactical for a sniper class as it lets me stay in one place for longer and gives me a good warning if the enemy is coming to flush me out (particularly if placed somewhere that covers more than one route to your position).

Answer (score 0):

For the last part of your question, you can relocate it just like a sentry gun, or similar equipment.  If you move close to it, it give a "press button to pickup trophy system" option.  The button depends on the platform your playing MW3 on.